# Delphi Ambiguous Overloaded Call to MkDir

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm getting the following error message when I attempt to call MkDir

> [Error] DBaseReindexer.dpr(22): Ambiguous overloaded call to `MkDir`

I've tried the following things and they all return the same error.

```
MkDir('test');

var
  Dir: String;
begin
  Dir := 'test';
  MkDir(Dir);
end;

const
  Dir = 'test';
begin
  MkDir(Dir);
end;
```

From looking at the source, there's a version that takes a string, and a version that takes a PChar. I'm not sure how my string would be ambiguous between those two types.

---

Code to reproduce the error (from comments):

```
program Project1; 
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE} 
uses SysUtils, System; 
begin 
  MkDir('Test');  
end.
```

Comment: I guess you need to fix `MkDir`, which we cannot see

Comment: It's in the system library. It's part of core Delphi.

Comment: Which Delphi version?

Comment: All three compiles fine here. Tested with D7 too..

Comment: Maybe do you have another `MkDir` method defined , try adding the unit name to the call like so  `System.MkDir('Foo')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code compiles fine in an empty project:

```
program Project1;

procedure Test;
const
  ConstStr = 'test';
var
  VarStr: string;
begin
  MkDir('Test');
  MkDir(ConstStr);
  MkDir(VarStr);
end;

begin
end.
```

So your problem is that somewhere else in your code you have defined an incompatible overload for `MkDir`. For instance this program:

```
program Project1;

procedure MkDir(const S: string); overload;
begin
end;

procedure Test;
const
  ConstStr = 'test';
var
  VarStr: string;
begin
  MkDir('Test');
  MkDir(ConstStr);
  MkDir(VarStr);
end;

begin
end.
```

produces the following compiler errors:

```
[dcc32 Error] Project1.dpr(13): E2251 Ambiguous overloaded call to 'MkDir'
  System.pas(5512): Related method: procedure MkDir(const string);
  Project1.dpr(3): Related method: procedure MkDir(const string);
[dcc32 Error] Project1.dpr(14): E2251 Ambiguous overloaded call to 'MkDir'
  System.pas(5512): Related method: procedure MkDir(const string);
  Project1.dpr(3): Related method: procedure MkDir(const string);
[dcc32 Error] Project1.dpr(15): E2251 Ambiguous overloaded call to 'MkDir'
  System.pas(5512): Related method: procedure MkDir(const string);
  Project1.dpr(3): Related method: procedure MkDir(const string);
```

Notice how the compiler helpfully tells you which two methods cannot be disambiguated. If you read the full compiler error message then it will take you to the cause of your problem.

Older Delphi versions don't give you the extra information. So if you are in that position, you will have to search your source code for the extra `MkDir`.

**Update**

Following the edit to the question that adds code, we can see that the incompatible overload arises from a rather surprising source. Your code is:

```
program Project1; 
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE} 
uses SysUtils, System; 
begin 
  MkDir('Test');  
end.
```

Well, `System` is automatically included in every unit and it is a compiler defect that the compiler gets past the `uses` clause. But the erroneous second inclusion of `System` is what is causing the ambiguity.

Modern versions of Delphi fix this problem and your code results in

```
[dcc32 Error] E2004 Identifier redeclared: 'System'
```

Clearly the solution is to remove the spurious use of `System`.

Comment: Explicitly using the system namespace works. Some how either SysUtils or StrUtils overwrite MkDir. Which is odd, because neither of them have that method.

Comment: No, try creating a new console application with the following code `program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  System;

begin
  MkDir('Test');
  { TODO -oUser -cConsole Main : Insert code here }
end.
` If it's not prepended with System., it fails.

Comment: D7 is not that helpful.

Comment: @mpt - You can't use 'system' twice, remove it. Apparently you can in D7. Anyway, remove it from the uses.

Comment: @mpthrapp: The System unit is automatically included by the compiler. You never have to add it to your uses clause under any circumstances. This has always been the case with every version of Delphi.

Comment: @KenWhite Ahhh, okay. Thanks. I'm not quite sure why I thought I did, but that fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: This answer currently does not accurately diagnose the problem. The actual case is, it's a compiler error where it allows a unit name to be included twice.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I've addressed that. FWIW, I think the original answer did diagnose the problem reasonably. *So your problem is that somewhere else in your code you have defined an incompatible overload for MkDir.* I hypothesised one cause, but who could have seen the actual cause before the code arrived? What an unexpected surprise!! Anyway, thanks for prompting me.